# directed weighted graph with two weights as an adjacency matrix C++

Tags: c++, matrix, graph

Is this possible?

I'm making a directed weighted graph, using an adjacency matrix. Is it possible to have two weights using a matrix? I can visualize how to do this using an adjacency list, but that would entail rewriting all my code.

Here's the entirety of my code for this project. Yes, this is for school. No, I'm not asking you to do the work for me. I just can't seem to wrap my head around having two weights.

So basically, what I'm trying to do here is give the program two weights. I'll manage how to do the search and the actual cost calculations, I just can't figure out how I'm supposed to store two weights like this. The two weights are the time a train departs, and when it arrives. After that, I'll calculate the cost/path/etc. based on those two weights.

Can I have a matrix with two weights? How do I do that? I don't think a 3D matrix is what this lesson had in mind, though I think that would work (my idea being having a 3D matrix where z is just 2 deep so that I can store another integer "behind" the first one). I'd rather not, though, if possible.

As you can see, I mistook the purpose of the assignment and thought that just finding the difference between the two times and then storing that as the weight would work. But I need to know the difference between the departure of node x and the arrival of node y. So I think I need to pass those into the matrix and then calculate when I'm doing djikstra's to get the path cost.

Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

#define MAX_SIZE 100
#define INFINITY 999999999
using namespace std;

class graph_matrix
{
    public:
        graph_matrix();
        graph_matrix(int, int);
        void setEdge(int, int, int);
        void djikstra(int, int);

    private:
        int nodeCount;
        int edgeCount;
        int **matrix;
};

void graph_matrix::djikstra(int source, int destination)
{
    int distances[nodeCount];
    int minNode, minDistance;
    bool vertexSet[nodeCount];

    for(int i=0; i<nodeCount; i++)
    {
        distances[i] = INFINITY;
        vertexSet[i] = false;
    }

    distances[source] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<nodeCount-1; i++)
    {
        minNode = INFINITY;
        minDistance = INFINITY;

        for(int vert = 0; vert<nodeCount; vert++)
        {
            if(vertexSet[vert] == false && distances[vert] <= minDistance)
            {
                minDistance = distances[vert];
                minNode = vert;
            }
        }

        vertexSet[minNode] = true;

        for(int vert = 0; vert<nodeCount; vert++)
        {
            if(vertexSet[vert] == false && matrix[minNode][vert])
            {
                if(distances[minNode] != INFINITY && distances[minNode] + matrix[minNode][vert] < distances[vert])
                {
                    distances[vert] = distances[minNode] + matrix[minNode][vert];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(distances[destination] < 60)
    {
        cout << distances[destination] << " minutes." << endl;  
    }

    else if(distances[destination] > 60)
    {
        cout << (distances[destination] - distances[destination]%60)/60 << " hours and " << distances[destination]%60 << " minutes." << endl;
    }
}

graph_matrix::graph_matrix()
{
    nodeCount = 0;
    edgeCount = 0;
    matrix = NULL;
}

graph_matrix::graph_matrix(int nodes, int edges)
{
    nodeCount = nodes + 1;
    edgeCount = edges;

    matrix = new int *[nodeCount];

    for (int i = 0; i <= nodeCount; i++)
        matrix[i] = new int[nodeCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < nodeCount; x++)
            matrix[i][x] = 0;
    }
}

void graph_matrix::setEdge(int source, int destination, int weight)
{
    matrix[source][destination] = weight;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream file;

    int statNumber, departStat, arriveStat, departTime, arriveTime, travelTime;
    string statName[MAX_SIZE];

    graph_matrix *gm = NULL;

    file.open("stations.dat");

    int stations = 0; //nodes
    int tracks = 0; //edges

    while(file >> statNumber)
    {
        file >> statName[statNumber];
        stations++;
    }

    file.close();

    file.open("trains.dat");


    while(file >> departStat)
    {
        file >> departStat;//I tried just using 'file;' here, but it didn't work. I didn't see any harm in passing it to a variable, though.
        file >> departStat;
        file >> departStat;
        tracks++;
        //I'm sure this is the least elegant way of doing this, but this is what my brain came up with
    }

    file.close();

    file.open("trains.dat");

    gm = new graph_matrix(stations, tracks);

    while(file >> departStat)
    {
        file >> arriveStat;
        file >> departTime;
        file >> arriveTime;
        travelTime = arriveTime - departTime; //At first, I thought this is what I needed.

        gm->setEdge(departStat, arriveStat, travelTime);
    }

    file.close();

    int menuin, numberin, departin, arrivein;
    string stationin;
    bool done = false;

    cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "        TRAIN MATE 3000            " << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl << endl << endl;

    while(!done)
    {
        cout << "Options" << endl;
        cout << "(1) - Look up station by number" << endl;
        cout << "(2) - Look up station by name" << endl;
        cout << "(3) - Find nonstop train" << endl;
        cout << "(4) - Is service available" << endl;
        cout << "(5) - Shortest ride time" << endl;
        cout << "(6) - Quit" << endl << endl;

        cout << "?: ";

        cin >> menuin;

        cout << endl;

        switch (menuin)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                cout << ">Enter station number: ";
                cin >> numberin;
                cout << endl << ">>Station " << numberin << ": " << statName[numberin] << endl << endl;
                break;
            }

            case 2:
            {
                cout << ">Enter station name: ";
                cin >> stationin;
                for(int i=0; i<=stations; i++)
                {
                    if(stationin.compare(statName[i]) == 0)
                    {
                        cout << endl << ">>Station " << i << ": " << statName[i] << endl << endl;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

            case 3:
            {
                cout << ">Enter departure station number: ";
                cin >> departin;
                cout << ">Enter arrival station number: ";
                cin >> arrivein;
                //do something to find if there's an edge
                break;
            }

            case 4:
            {
                cout << ">Enter departure station number: ";
                cin >> departin;
                cout << ">Enter arrival station number: ";
                cin >> arrivein;
                //do something to find if there's a path
                break;
            }

            case 5:
            {
                cout << ">Enter departure station number: ";
                cin >> departin;
                cout << ">Enter arrival station number: ";
                cin >> arrivein;
                cout << endl << ">>To go from " << statName[departin] << " to "<< statName[arrivein] << ", you will need to ride the train for ";
                gm->djikstra(departin, arrivein);
                cout << endl;
                break;
            }

            case 6:
            {
                done = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry my main is pretty long. Don't worry about any of that. I'm just asking about the matrix itself, but I figured I'd give the whole context.

Comment: Wait. I think I might be on to something with that 3D matrix thing.

Can I just change the matrix to something like matrix[x][y][z] where z is just how I differentiate between arrival and departure?

Comment: Instead of a matrix of `int`, how about a matrix of `Edge`, where `Edge` is a struct you define which contains both weights?

Comment: I absolutely love that idea. It's so simple. I've already implemented it in the matrix, now I just need to figure out the logic for djikstra's. Shouldn't be too hard. Thank you!